# is there way to update iOS app without AppStore?

Tags: ios

I want to publish my app in AppStore and update that published app without Appstore!
I wand send new update directly from server to the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all the work server side.

For example you can do all your UI from the backend. Sending through `JSON` all the `text`, `size`, `space`, `color`, `constraints` etc... That way you can update your App without the `AppStore`. But it is a lot of work to implement in the first place.

Same logic can be applied for features within the App, you can disable or activate them from the server too.

But all your App needs to be build that way.

I can't see an other alternative to "update" the App without the Appstore.

It really depends on what kind of update you want to achieve.

Comment: Please explain more. I need an update to change the entire program to another.
is there any tutorial?

Comment: What do you mean  by "entire program", the content? Some text?

Comment: For example . Make an editor program with a server-side update to a social network or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Binary Update you should use the App Store, if it's a config update, you can use Firebase Remote Config.